# Setting up a simple server/client, getting "java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect"

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket, connectexception

I'm struggling with setting up my first server/client connection. My GUI has a dialog. Upon pressing a Send Button inside of that, I call `client.connect().`

It works the first time, but when I go ahead and reopen the dialog (it closes by itself after pressing Send) and attempt to do the same again, I will get the "connection refused" error. I suspect this is due to the server still being connected to the original socket and the Button Event triggering `client.connect()` again. (Which will try to connect a new one). But I don't know how I can make sure this doesn't happen. I somehow have to close the client Socket once the dialog closes, right? How do I implement this? Or does the problem lie somewhere else? This was just a guess that feels kinda right.

Here's my `Client` class (it includes the `connect()` method called above):

```
public class Client extends Application
{
    private String string = "";
    Socket s;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {
        VBox root = new VBox();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 380, 200);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        Client client = new Client();
        client.connect();
        launch(args);
    }

    public void connect() throws UnknownHostException, IOException
    {
        s = new Socket("localhost",3000);
        System.out.println("Connected");
        PrintWriter dos = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());
        dos.println(string);
        dos.flush();
    }
}
```

And here's my `Server` class:

```
public class Server
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException
    {
        ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket (3000);
        Socket s = server.accept();
        System.out.println("Connected");
        BufferedReader dis = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
        System.out.println(dis.readLine());
    }
}
```

Please note this is my first time ever setting up Server/Client in java, hence the localhost to try it out and the probably obvious problem.

Comment: The server only accepts one connection and reads one line, then it exits. You need a loop. You also need to read the custom Networking section of the Java Tutorial.

Comment: I will look right into it. Thank you for the directions!